# Creation of array and append value inside closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this code -

```
var gArray = (function (value) {
    var array = [];
    return function () {
        array.push(value);
        return array;
    }
}());

gArray(1);
gArray(2);
gArray(3);
```

I am expecting to this code snippet  `[1, 2, 3]`

but i am getting `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer function is a self-invoked function. That means that it will be executed as soon as `()` is reached. In this particular case, it's returning:

```
function () {
    array.push(value);
    return array;
}
```

which is taking value as `undefined`. To solve this issue, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
var gArray = (function () {
    var array = [];
    return function (value) {
        array.push(value);
        return array;
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 5):

The `gArray` function doesn't have an argument, the immediately invoked function does, but you pass nothing when you call it:

```
var gArray = (function (value) { //<- Argument of IIFE
    var array = [];
    return function () { //<- No arguments for gArray
        array.push(value);
        return array;
    }
}()); //<- No arguments passed to IIFE
```

What you need is to define an argument for the returned function, which is `gArray`:

```
var gArray = (function () {
    var array = [];
    return function (value) {
        array.push(value);
        return array;
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [];

function addToArray(value){
        myArray.push(value);
        console.log(value + " was added to " + myArray);
}

addToArray(1);
addToArray(2);
addToArray(3);
```

**If you give back myArray console will say [1, 2, 3]**

Comment: Oh my bad. Maybe someone else will find this useful.

Comment: I think the point of the OP is to use a closure so *myArray* is not global.

Comment: @raduation Based on his usage of gArray, it would seem that no, he has no intentions of having multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var array = [];` to `this.array = [];`.

It needs to have the right scope.

Comment: *this* has nothing do with scope, or the OP's issue (*this* is the global object, or *undefined* in strict mode). The OP's issue is only obliquely related to scope.

Answer (score -2):

This is the best way to do it:

```js
const array = [];
const pushArray = function(value, array) {
    array.push(value);

    return array;
};

pushArray(1, array);
pushArray(2, array);
pushArray(3, array);
```